# Prevent PHP require_once from ever running

Tags: php, require-once

Debugging someone else's PHP code, I'd like to selectively override one of their classes.  The class is included via:

```
require_once('classname.php');
```

But, that appears in various places in the application.  I'd rather 'simulate' the `require_once`, so that it never gets run at all.  I.e. just define `class classname` as I want it.  Then, the next time the file was `require_once`'ed, it'd be flagged as already-loaded and thus not reloaded.

I can create a classname.php file of my own, but I'd rather keep the testing I'm doing contained to a single file, as I'm doing this possibly for many classes, and I'd like easier control over the overriding.

In Perl, what I'd want to do would be:

```
$INC{'classname.pm'} = 1;
```

Is there a way to access PHP's equivalent of Perl's `%INC`?

**Update**: Consistently surprised by what PHP doesn't let you do...

My workaround was to use [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php)'s `runkit_method_redefine`.  I load the classes I was trying to prevent loading, and then redefine all the methods I was trying to 'mock', e.g.:

```
require_once('classname.php');
runkit_method_redefine('classname','method','$params','return "testdata";');
```

Comment: If you want newclass.php included instead of classname.php, why not add two lines to the top of classname.php?: `require_once 'newclass.php'; return;`

Comment: Because I'm doing this for many classes, I don't want to alter the original class files.  And because I want better control, I'd rather have a non-file-based solution.  (i.e. I'll probably settle for adding a /tmp dir to include_path and creating only the class files I want overridden.)

Comment: Benizi dont worry I know what you mean, and its a top question. I couldnt find anything in PHP, its such a limited language. I stil have no clue how it became so popular when perl exists. I guess people are too lazy to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Place:

```
<?php return; ?>
```

at the very top of `classname.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

> Then, the next time the file was require_once'ed, it'd be flagged as already-loaded and thus not reloaded.

require_once does this for you..

Additionally you could use something hacky like

```
if(!class_exists("my_class")) {
  class my_class {}  // define your class here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, was probably unclear in the explanation: the 'next time' is the first time.  I want, in my own code without creating another file, to prevent `require_once('somefile.php');` from ever loading somefile.php.  Your class_exists gets the gist of why I want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking what you mean is that it's entirely possible that there is another "required_once" somewhere else in the code that would cause yours to be overwritten.

There are two things you can do:

1) Hunt down the first "required" and then comment it out.

2) Go into the class file and include your class and return before the other class is defined.